# Trying to make 10 columns in Java for loop with if statement

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm using a for loop in Java to make 10 columns of numbers. I'm able to generate all the numbers, but I can't get the output to be in 10 columns. 
Here is what I have:

```
    int column = 10;
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i ++){
    if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 6 == 0){

        System.out.println(i + " ");
        if ((counter % column) == 0) {
            System.out.println();
            counter = 0;
        }
        counter++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are printing only when number is divisible by 30 (`x % 5` & `x % 6`) - this is not necessary. So remove that `if`.

Second - when you are printing a number, you are also printing a newline - so replace

```
System.out.println(i + " ");
```

with

```
System.out.print(i + " ");
```

Third, you want to emit a newline every 10 elements, so you can replace

```
(counter % column) == 0
```

with

```
(counter % 10) == 0
```

Comment: Thank you! Even just changing println to print fixed my problem.